# User created in database but mail not sent without error

Tags: php, symfony, email, mailer

When creating a user, I want to send an email with an account validation link.

The user account is created in the database but no email is sent. Being in dev, I use MailHog to use a local SMTP server.

.env.local :

```
MAILER_DSN=smtp://admin:admin@0.0.0.0:1025
```

RegisterService.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Service\User;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Component\Mailer\MailerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Mime\TemplatedEmail;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Address;

class RegisterService
{
    private $doctrine;
    private $passwordHasher;
    private $userRepository;
    private $mailer;

    public function __construct(
        ManagerRegistry $doctrine,
        UserPasswordHasherInterface $passwordHasher,
        UserRepository $userRepository,
        MailerInterface $mailer
    )
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
        $this->passwordHasher = $passwordHasher;
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }

    // Inscription d'un nouvel utilisateur
    public function register($data)
    {
        // Vérification des données utilisateur
        $dataStatus = $this->verificationData($data);

        if ($dataStatus === false) {
            return 'error';
        }    

if ($this->userRepository->findByUsernameOrEmail($data->username, $data->email) == []) {
        $em = $this->doctrine->getManager();

        $user = new User;
        $user->setPseudo($data->username);
        $user->setEmail($data->email);
        $hashedPassword = $this->passwordHasher->hashPassword(
            $user,
            $data->password
        );
        $user->setPassword($hashedPassword);

        $token = uniqid();
        $user->setToken($token);

        $email = (new TemplatedEmail())
        ->from('me@mail.com')
        ->to(new Address($user->getEmail()))
        ->subject('Hello world!')
        ->htmlTemplate('emails/validation.html.twig')
        ->context([
            'pseudo' => $user->getPseudo(),
            'token' => $token,
        ]);

        $this->mailer->send($email);

        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        return true;
    } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I tried to host the back on my web server, with an smtp server, but it's the same, no email sent

Comment: Have you tried `MAILER_DSN=smtp://localhost:1025`?

Comment: Yes Bossman, but it's the same

Comment: I take it you have [installed MailHog](https://gist.github.com/dipenparmar12/4e6cd50d8d1303d5e914742f62659116) (Linux/Win/Mac).. Try testing locally from terminal etc..

Comment: Yes, I use mailhog for other symfony projects and it works

Comment: have you checked all the assumptions? most significantly that 1. the code up until mailer->send is actually called and 2. that the mailer is some sensible class? also, your mailer configuration overall would be nice to see, so other users can see what's in there. could imagine that it's just put in some queue to rot.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Symfony Mailer here, you also need to tell the mailer it has to make use of your MAILER_DSN variable in `config/packages/mailer.yaml`. The syntax below should work.

```yaml
framework:
  mailer:
    dsn: '%env(MAILER_DSN)%'
```

Comment: Yes I have this file with this content in config/packages/mailer.yaml